# Does Javers support DB2 and DB2/400?

Tags: javers

In release 3.7.8, it was stated that the support was added for DB2 and DB2/400. However, in 3.14.0, it was stated that the experimental support was discontinued.

Going through the API, it was noted that there's no dialect for DB2. As such, I guess the support for DB2 was removed.

I would like to find out whether DB2 support is still in the plan for Javers or abandoned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have abandoned support for DB2 database, as we can't find a way how to run integration tests for it.